# How to chain 3 promises in axios?

Tags: axios

I am trying to chain together 3 different responses in axios. I can chain together two of the .then promises, but the third chain does not seem to work. I am new to using alpine js, and especially axios for that matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my chains:

```
        function MainFun() {
        return {
        FLA: '',
        Date: '',
        Three: '',
        
        Display_FLA: [],
        Dates: [],
        Threes: [],
        
        
        // Chains
        // Chain 1
        
        DisplayFLA() {
             axios.get('/DisplayFLA_Dropdown').then(resp => {
                  this.Display_FLA = resp.data
             });
           },
        }
        
        // Chain 2 - works
        
            DisplayDates() {
                axios.post(
                    '/DisplayFLA_DropdownDisplayDate', {
                    FLA:this.FLA
                }).then(resp => [
                    this.Dates = resp.data
                ])
            },
        
// EDIT: FOR THIRD PROMISE ---  I am trying to take the value of the 
   2nd promise, which derives from the 1st promise, and set it equal to 
        the third promise

        // Cannot figure out how to make third chain work
            DisplayThree() {
                axios.post('/DisplayTableThree', {
                    Date:this.Date
                }).then(resp => [
                    this.Threes = resp.data
                ])
            },
        
    
        
    
        // Calls first chain
            init() {
                this.DisplayFLA();
            }
        }
        }
```